# How to install mPDF with Composer in Plesk Obsidian

Tags: composer-php, plesk, mpdf

I would like to know how to install mPDF on a particular site hosted on a server with Plesk Obsidian running on CentOS 6.10 (Final).

I tried to open Php Composer but the only option I have is `Find your Composer applications` and there is no option to install new packages.

On the web I read that I should create a file named *composer.json* and put it in the project directory but I have no idea where to create the directory, how to call the directory and what to put inside this file!

Thanks for your help!